# How to get Subsite Or QueryString using Regx

Tags: regex

I have a question about regex to get information from a URL.

It may be discussed earlier but I am looking for a mix approach.

If user is either providing a subsite or user is providing a query string and depending on condition I want to add a rule in URL Requests.

Regex : `/([^,]*)`
Input : `youtube.com/data/beta`

I am getting **data/beta**, which is what I am looking for.

but when I am passing input as `http://youtube.com/data/beta`, it is giving me `/youtube..../`, and that is correct, but I want to exclude first `//[DomainName]`.

Note: I can't exclude on `youtube.com`, as I am going to use this regex in some rule, so please send me answer or comment which can work on any kind of URL.

Answer (score 0):

## Description

```
^(?:https?:\/\/)?[^\/]+\/|([^?\n]+)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

This regular expression will do the following:

- match strings starting with `http://` or `https://`
- skip the domain name
- capture the substring after the domain name and before the query string

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/zC4gZ6/1

**Sample text**

```
youtube.com/data/beta
http://youtube.com/data/beta?Droid=This_is_not_the_droid_you_are_looking_for
```

**Sample Matches**

```
[1][0] = youtube.com/data/beta
[1][1] = data/beta

[2][0] = http://youtube.com/data/beta
[2][1] = data/beta
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of a "line"
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    http                     'http'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    s?                       's' (optional (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    :                        ':'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \/                       '/'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \/                       '/'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^\/]+                   any character except: '\/' (1 or more
                           times (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \/                       '/'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^?\n]+                  any character except: '?', '\n'
                             (newline) (1 or more times (matching the
                             most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

## Extra Credit

To include the query strings if they exist then add `(?:\?(.*?))?$`
to the end of the above expression so it looks like this.

```
^(?:https?:\/\/)?[^\/]+\/([^?\n]+)(?:\?(.*?))?$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: Thanks Ro Yo, you are awesome. But I just have one question, how can I include query strings also into result?

Comment: I just provided an update at the end of my answer to cover the query strings portion. This allows the query string portion to exist or not exist.